# OR Conditional statement for node in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I'm trying to do the following in my jenkinsfile with the purpose that if "master" is being used, then run in "slave". Is that what the following conditional does in scripted pipeline? If not, is there a better/right way?

```
node ("master||slave") {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have same **label** name for different nodes in Jenkins and it will automatically pick the available node.
2. You can also assign how many build should execute in a node by putting the number of executor to node.

[image]

Please folloe the link for more [info](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Using+Labels+for+Resource+Assignment+and+Job+Queuing+in+Jenkins)